# Initialize class parameter with a function in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to initialize a class parameter with a function in Scala?

Example:

```
def square(x: Int) = x*x

class Foo(val x: Int = square(x))
```

This doesn't compile but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: It will work if you will use something like this: `square(somethingOtherThanX)`. But you can't at the same time provide an argument and use it's default value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to guess what you're trying to achieve, but let me have a go:

```
class Foo private (val x: Int)

object Foo {
  def apply(x: Int) = new Foo(square(x))
}
```

Note that if you try this in the REPL, you must enter both the class and its companion object at the same time (in paste mode, via `:pa`), or the `object Foo` won't have access to the private class constructor.

This applies the `square` function to the parameter `x` before creating a `Foo` instance:

```
scala> Foo(3).x
res1: Int = 9
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because you try to calculate `x` based on `x` (without having any kind of base case). You could do the following:

```
class Foo(_x: Int) {
  val x = square(_x)
}

println(new Foo(10).x) // 100
```

**EDIT**

You could also generalise this and implicitly pass a function to the class constructor that transforms `x`:

```
implicit val square = (x: Int) => x*x

class Foo(private val _x: Int)(implicit f: Int => Int) {
  val x = f(_x)
}

println(new Foo(10).x) // 100
```

This unfortunately **doesn't compile as-is** (Scala 2.9.2, 2.10.0), because there is another implicit in scope (`Predef.conforms`). I don't know how to overcome this ambiguity, but it should certainly be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is.. you can initialize a class with a function ! :)

```
  class Foo(f : Int => Int)

  def square(x : Int) = x*x                     

  val foo = new Foo(square)
```

Or Probably you must be looking for this.

```
  class Foo(f : Int => Int, _p1 : Int){
   val p1 = f(_p1)
  }

  def square(x : Int) = x*x                       //> square: (x: Int)Int
  def add2(x : Int) = x+2                         //> add2: (x: Int)Int

  val fooSqr = new Foo(square,5)                  
  fooSqr.p1                                       //> res0: Int = 25

  val fooAdd2 =  new Foo(add2,5)                 
  fooAdd2.p1                                      //> res1: Int = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use arbitrary expressions when defining the default value ([source](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/named_and_default_parameters_in_scala.html)).

Your problem is that you can not use x on the right hand side of the initialization, because x is probably neither declared nor initialized at that point.